# Contacts can only be linked to Accounts with ownership set to private

Tags: validation-rule

I have a requirement in a salesforce project.

**Contacts can only be linked with an account that has Ownership field set to private.**

I simply did a validation rule on Contact :
`NOT(ISPICKVAL(Account.Ownership, "Private"))`

but i was told there is a better way of doing this

**My question is what are other ways to achieve this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [lookup filter](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.fields_lookup_filters.htm&type=5) is probably what your reviewer had in mind.

While a validation rule will prevent invalid data from being saved, a lookup filter can be configured so that users cannot select invalid data in the first place. It's better in the sense that it intervenes sooner in your user's workflow. If the workflow is `navigate to record page -> edit record -> save record`, then a lookup filter acts in the "edit record" part whereas a validation rule acts in the "save record" part.

It also generally doesn't present an error to your users. Users' minds tend to just go blank whenever an error is presented (no matter how simple/clear/non-scary the error message is). No error = less chance they'll open a support ticket with you/your Salesforce admins.

One thing to be aware of is that lookup filters have a limit to the number of records that they can display. I'd have to dig through some old notes and/or some old Salesforce support tickets to confirm, but from memory...

- Salesforce uses the filter to get up to 2000 potential values
- This happens before Salesforce takes the user-supplied field value into account
- If your user tries to search for a valid value, but that value is not included in the pre-filtered list (of 2000 records), then the user-supplied value will not return any results (and they won't be able to use that value, even if it would satisfy the lookup filter)

So the moral of the story here is that you probably want to make lookup filters be more specific. Having an additional condition or two beyond "Account Ownership is Private" would help prevent the issue mentioned above.